# Type of elements of list created without a type

Tags: java

I am confused due to this example found on a book saying that the type of "elt" is Object which I think is False. I believe it is Integer.

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(var el:list)
    System.out.println(el);
```

But when I add an element to the list and check whether the type is Integer it prints True(Integer)

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        var x1 = 1;
        list.add(x1);
        for(var el:list)
            System.out.println(el instanceof Integer);
```

I know by default List elements are of Type Object if no type is specified but in the example above the Integer type is specified on the right side so "el" type is Integer right?

Comment: "the Integer type is specified on the right side (Integer)" - yes, but that's not the type of the variable.

Comment: are you using `java` or `javascript`?

Comment: `for (Integer el : list)` will not compile. `for (Object el : list)` will.

Comment: @user2342558 I'm using java.

Comment: @Jon Skeet , I checked the type of the variable it says Integer.

Comment: @knittl I am talking about a for loop using var.

Comment: @clorzs: How *exactly* did you check the type of the variable? (And which variable do you mean?) You need to be very aware of the difference between the compile-time type of a variable, and the execution-time type of a variable's value.

Answer (score 3):

> I am confused due to this example found on a book saying that the type of "elt" is Object which I think is False. I believe it is Integer.

No, the type of the `elt` *variable* is `Object`, because the type of `list` *variable* is just the raw `List` type - not `ArrayList`, and not `ArrayList<Integer>`. The type is the type it's declared as - just `List`.

> But when I add an element to the list and check whether the type is Integer it prints True(Integer)

Yes, that's because you're testing the *execution-time* type of the element, which is very different from the *compile-time* type of the `elt` variable.

To give a simpler example, consider:

```java
Object obj = "test";
// Prints true, because at execution time the value of obj is a reference
// to a String object.
System.out.println(obj instanceof String);

// But this won't compile, because the *compile-time* type of obj is Object,
// not String.
System.out.println(obj.length());
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right I tried the following
<< Integer x2 = list.get(0);>> and it does not compile saying "cant assign an Object to an Integer"